# Android app works on simulator but gives black screen on device

Tags: android

I just tested my app on a samsung galaxy note but it shows just a black screen. I just copied the apk file from the bin folder of my project on my device.

I noticed that the launcher icon is missing on device and that the app takes 48 KB space on device but 148 KB space on simulator. On the simulator the app runs just fine.

I retrieved the log from device but it has no significant information. It just says

```
12-26 16:27:36.270 I/ActivityManager( 2774): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.foo.bar/.mdjActivity } from pid 3020
```

Any ideas whats wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you building your app in release mode? Signed, aligned, proguard-optimized? Any specific layouts or initialization calls?

Comment: I think its in debug mode, I did nothing special to my project, just started and always tested on simulator. I use action bar library https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

Comment: Did you install the app or just copy it over?

Comment: Try to uninstall any previous version of the app.

Comment: I uninstalled the app, still same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just install the app from within eclipse? Probably you are using a wrong .apk file. Try connecting your device to eclipse and installing from there.

Another option is to use the `export android project` menu option in the `export` menu you get when you rightclick on the project. That gives you a working apk.